# Why are imported functions called so indirectly in Linux?

Tags: linux, glibc, dynamic-linking, dlopen

Consider a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Running it with GDB, having set `LD_BIND_NOW=1` for simplicity, I can observe the following:

```
$ gdb -q ./test -ex 'b main' -ex r
Reading symbols from ./test...done.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048420
Starting program: /tmp/test 

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048420 in main ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804841d <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x0804841e <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
=> 0x08048420 <+3>:     and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x08048423 <+6>:     sub    esp,0x10
   0x08048426 <+9>:     mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048500
   0x0804842d <+16>:    call   0x80482c0 <puts@plt>
   0x08048432 <+21>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x08048437 <+26>:    leave  
   0x08048438 <+27>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) si 4
0x080482c0 in puts@plt ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function puts@plt:
=> 0x080482c0 <+0>:     jmp    DWORD PTR ds:0x8049670
   0x080482c6 <+6>:     push   0x0
   0x080482cb <+11>:    jmp    0x80482b0
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) si
_IO_puts (str=0x8048500 "Hello") at ioputs.c:35
35      {
(gdb)
```

Apparently, after binding the PLT entry to the function, we still do a two-step call:

1. `call puts@plt`
2. `jmp [ds:puts_address]`

Comparing this with how it's implemented in Win32, there all calls of imported functions, e.g. `MessageBoxA`, are done like

```
call [ds:MessageBoxA_address]
```

i.e. in a single step.

Even if taking lazy binding into account, it's still possible to have e.g. `[puts_address]` contain the call to `_dl_runtime_resolve` or whatever is needed on startup, so the one-step indirect call would still work.

So what's the reason for such a complication? Is this some sort of branch prediction or branch target prediction optimization?

**EDIT** in response to [Employed Russian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32682697/673852) (v2)

What I actually mean is that this indirection of `call PLT; jump [GOT]` is redundant even in the context of lazy binding. Consider the following example (relies on compilation without optimizations by gcc):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
    {
        puts("Hello");
        __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running it (with `LD_BIND_NOW` unset) in GDB:

```
$ gdb ./test -ex 'b main' -ex r -ex disas/r
Reading symbols from ./test...done.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048387
Starting program: /tmp/test 

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048387 in main ()
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   ...
   0x08048397 <+19>:    c7 04 24 80 84 04 08    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048480
   0x0804839e <+26>:    e8 11 ff ff ff  call   0x80482b4 <puts@plt>
   0x080483a3 <+31>:    90      nop
   0x080483a4 <+32>:    83 44 24 1c 01  add    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x1
   ...
```

Disassembling `puts@plt`, we can see the address of GOT entry for `puts`:

```
(gdb) disas 'puts@plt'
Dump of assembler code for function puts@plt:
   0x080482b4 <+0>:     jmp    DWORD PTR ds:0x8049580
   0x080482ba <+6>:     push   0x10
   0x080482bf <+11>:    jmp    0x8048284
End of assembler dump.
```

So we see it's 0x8049580. We can patch our code for `main()` to change `e8 11 ff ff ff 90` (address 0x8048e9e) to indirect call to GOT entry, i.e. `call [ds:0x8049580]`: `ff 15 80 95 04 08`:

```
(gdb) set *(uint64_t*)0x804839e=0x44830804958015ff
(gdb) disas/r
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   ...
   0x08048397 <+19>:    c7 04 24 80 84 04 08    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048480
   0x0804839e <+26>:    ff 15 80 95 04 08       call   DWORD PTR ds:0x8049580
   0x080483a4 <+32>:    83 44 24 1c 01  add    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x1
   ...
```

Running the program after this still gives:

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hello
Hello
Hello
[Inferior 1 (process 14678) exited normally]
```

I.e. the first call did the lazy binding, and the next two just used the result of fixup (you can trace it yourself if you don't believe).

So **the question remains**: why is this way of calling not used by GCC?

Comment: I've seen this too while writing Elf loaders etc., and as far as I can tell it optimizes the relocation table: all external functions are defined only once, and so only 1 memory address needs to be relocated. Otherwise, all calls throughout the code referencing the same external function must be resolved. But whether this is the real reason, I don't know..

Comment: The downside of Windows **thunking** is that it's not possible for the library to call functions exported by the executable without going through a few more hoops, whereas on Linux functions exported by both the libraries and the executable go into a common symbol pool.

Comment: Your edit refers to address `0x8049580`, which does *not* appear anywhere in your original disassembly. That makes it hard to understand what your patched `CALL` is a call to. Can you edit your question so that the addresses and disassembly are *consistent*?

Comment: @EmployedRussian good point, added the missing step. I guess the address changed due to changed source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Apparently, after binding the PLT entry to the function, we still do a two-step call:
>
> ```
> call puts@plt
> jmp [ds:puts_address]
> ```

The compiler and linker can't know that you are going to set `LD_BIND_NOW=1` at runtime, and so can't go back in time and re-write generated code to use direct `call [puts_address]`.

See also [recent](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-05/msg00001.html) `-fno-plt` [patches](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-05/msg00225.html) on the gcc-patches mailing list.

> Win32

Win32 doesn't allow lazy function resolution (at least not by default). In other words, they compile / link code that *only* works as if `LD_BIND_NOW=1` is hard-coded at compile / link time. Some history [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/16/54938.aspx).

> it's still possible to have e.g. `[puts_address]` contain the call to `_dl_runtime_resolve` or whatever is needed on startup, so the one-step indirect call would still work.

I think you are confused. The `[puts_address]` *does* contain `_dl_runtime_resolve` at startup (well, not exactly. [Gory details](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/)). Your question is "why can't the call go directly to `[puts_address]`, why is `puts@plt` needed?".

The answer is that `_dl_runtime_resolve` needs to know *which* function it is resolving. It can't deduce that info from arguments to `puts`. The entire raison d'être of `puts@plt` is exactly to supply that info to `_dl_runtime_resolve`.

**Update:**

> Why can't `call <puts@plt>` be replaced with `call *[puts@GOT]`.

The answer is provided in the first `-fno-plt` [patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-05/msg00001.html) I referenced:

"This comes with  caveats. This cannot be generally done for all
functions marked extern as it is impossible for the compiler to say if
a function is "truly extern" (defined in a shared library). If a
function is not truly extern(ends up defined in the final executable),
then calling it indirectly is a performance penalty as it could have
been a direct call."

You could then ask: why can't the linker (which knows whether `puts` is defined in the same binary or in a separate DSO) rewrite the `call *[puts@GOT]` back into `call <puts@plt>`?

The answer is that these are different instructions (different op-codes), and linkers generally do not change instructions, only addresses within instructions (in response to relocation entries).

In theory the linker *could* do this, but no-one's bothered yet.

Comment: Aha, the last paragraph seems to be exactly what I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, wait. Why can't the compiler just do `call [ds:0x8049670]` instead of calling to an instruction which performs `jmp [ds:0x8049670]`?

Comment: @Ruslan We are going in circles. The answer is "lazy binding". You really should read the "Gory details" post to understand this.

Comment: I've read that article. It just tells why lazy binding is needed and how it's implemented. But it doesn't answer my question of _why it's implemented this way_. Please see my updated question for clarification.

Comment: @Ruslan You've read the article, but failed to *understand* it. Think about it: what parameter does `_dl_runtime_resolve` get in the original and in patched code? Hint: your patched example can *only* work when LD_BIND_NOW is set. You claim to have unset it, but you must not have done it correctly.

Comment: It gets the exact same parameter in both cases, because call to a jump is identical to call to target of the jump. Note: the parameter is pushed _after_ the jump, not before it, so there's nothing I'm doing wrong here. As for `LD_BIND_NOW`, you can check yourself, it does indeed work with this unset. I've already mentioned in the question edit that I've actually traced the program to make sure it calls `_dl_runtime_resolve` on first call and gets directly to `puts` on the following ones.

Comment: Ah, this does make sense now.